# Drive Second Monitor from Application

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Is it possible to drive a monitor directly from an application without having windows explorer or the mouse show up on the desktop? I have searched the web and cannot find any answers that are on topic.

Comment: At the very least you're going to require a driver for the graphics chip, so Windows will have to know about the display. I don't know if there's a way to have an active device without Windows extending the desktop to it. Would it be sufficient to have a window that covers the entire device and turns off the cursor while over it?

Comment: You should ask about your problem rather than your proposed solution. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?